# Scrapy installation error

Tags: python

I want to install scrapy on Ubuntu.

But the following error occurred.

I am using Ubuntu 16.
Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2 are installed together.

```
khhan@khhan-VirtualBox:~$ pip install scrapy
Collecting scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from scrapy)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
Collecting w3lib>=1.15.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached w3lib-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting service-identity (from scrapy)
  Using cached service_identity-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Using cached cssselect-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting parsel>=0.9.3 (from scrapy)
  Using cached parsel-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from scrapy)
Collecting cryptography>=1.3.4 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached cryptography-1.7.1.tar.gz
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
  Using cached incremental-16.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Collecting pyasn1-modules (from service-identity->scrapy)
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs (from service-identity->scrapy)
  Using cached attrs-16.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=11.3 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1h5y_f/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp_puCJLpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  running egg_info
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
  building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:434:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: 그런 파일이나 디렉터리가 없습니다
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: cryptography, pyOpenSSL, constantly, incremental, zope.interface, Twisted, w3lib, pyasn1-modules, attrs, service-identity, cssselect, parsel, PyDispatcher, scrapy
  Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1h5y_f/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0AKiJN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:434:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: 그런 파일이나 디렉터리가 없습니다
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1h5y_f/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0AKiJN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1h5y_f/cryptography/
```

Anyone to help me?

I've just searched on stackoverflow, but I'm asking the first question.

Comment: `fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are missing openssl on your machine.
Go install openssl

Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: @khhan yep! happy to help!